# How to access java variable(String) in JSP

Tags: jsp

It is my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Guru Registration Form</title>
<script type="javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Guru Register Form</h1>
<form action="home.jsp" method="get">
    <table style="with: 50%">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn"/></form>
</body>

</html>
```

There i want to see the value of java variable(fristName*)

Home.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>"My First Name: "</h1>
${firstName}

</body>
</html>
```

There i get input value from index.jsp and setting to string variable
LoginServlet.java:

```
package com.example.controller;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
String firstName;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
    request.setAttribute("first-name", firstName);


    // Do your Java job here.

    request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

}
```

Please help me wtih this. I caould not solve this problem. One more thing i use Maven. And i can share with pom.xml and web.xml

Answer (score 0):

in your servlet you have specified the key "first-name" in set attribute so to access it you need to specify the exact same key in get attribute

also you need to use expression tag to display the variable as below and use toString method and remove semicolon

```
   <h1>"My First Name: "</h1>
<%= request.getAttribute("first-name").toString() %>
```

Comment: `<%=` is an implicit call for toString() conversion, though it is not wrong.

Comment: yeah that's true, I'm learning as well so that was helpful, thank you

Comment: Sorry. I  edited my question. My purpose that access to the variable via ${variableName}. Can you solve this?